# The cycle class map with values in crystalline cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, crystalline-cohomology, frobenius-map

Let $ k = \mathbb{F}_q $ be a finite field of characteristic $ p > 0 $.

Let $ X $ be a smooth proper scheme of dimension $ d $ over $ k $.

Consider the associated $ K $ - linear cycle class map with values in crystalline cohomology, $$ \mathrm{cl}_X \ : \ \mathcal{Z}^{m} (X)_K / \sim_{ \mathrm{rat} } \ \ \to \ \ ( H_{ \mathrm{crys} }^{2m} (X/W(k))(m) \otimes_{ W(k) } K )^{ \mathrm{Fr}^{2m} } $$ as it is mentionned in the following link, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.08774.pdf , page, $ 4 $.

Sorry if i'm still novice in this fields. All what i would like to know, is, Why is the map $ \mathrm{cl}_X $ well-defined, and how is it defined ?

Thank you.

Comment: This 2002 PhD thesis looks relevant: "Cycle classes for algebraic De Rham
cohomology and crystalline cohomology" by Nicholas Ring, https://bonndoc.ulb.uni-bonn.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/20.500.11811/1828/0101.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y. Note that the definition of $cl_X(Z)$ is much easier if the components of $Z$ are smooth, it is the non-smooth case which is difficult.

Comment: NB. Your formulae would be rather more readable if you weren't using $k$ for two different things at once.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited the post above right now.  :-)

Comment: There is http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_2003__131_1_59_0/